# How can I use Serde with a JSON array with different objects for successes and errors?

Tags: json, rust, serde

I want to use Serde to create an array with error messages as well as proper objects:

```
extern crate serde; // 1.0.70
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive; // 1.0.70
extern crate serde_json; // 1.0.24

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct MyError {
    error: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct MyAge {
    age: i32,
    name: String,
}

fn get_results(ages: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<MyAge> {
    let mut results = vec![];
    for age in ages {
        if age < 100 && age > 0 {
            results.push(MyAge {
                age: age,
                name: String::from("The dude"),
            });
        } else {
            results.push(MyError {
                error: String::from(format!("{} is invalid age", age)),
            });
        }
    }
    results
}
```

When I pass in the Vec `[1, -6, 7]` I want to serialize to the JSON:

```
[{"age": 1, "name": "The dude"},{"error": "-6 is invalid age"},{"age": 7, "name": "The dude"}]
```

How do I do that? Knowing how to deserialize such an array would be nice as well.

Comment: please show what it currently serializes to.

Comment: @ker It doesn't searialize to anything. This isn't valid code. Because "MyError" and "MyAge" isn't compatible types.

Comment: ooooh... Have you tried using an enum instead? There's a million ways to solve your problem. The solutions have different amounts and types of code that you need to write yourself... Are you bound to that exact output format?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's one way of doing that:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive; // 1.0.117
extern crate serde; // 1.0.117
extern crate serde_json; // 1.0.59

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct MyError {
    error: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct MyAge {
    age: i32,
    name: String,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum AgeOrError {
    Age(MyAge),
    Error(MyError),
}

impl serde::Serialize for AgeOrError {
    fn serialize<S: serde::Serializer>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        match self {
            &AgeOrError::Age(ref my_age) => serializer.serialize_some(my_age),
            &AgeOrError::Error(ref my_error) => serializer.serialize_some(my_error),
        }
    }
}

enum AgeOrErrorField {
    Age,
    Name,
    Error,
}

impl<'de> serde::Deserialize<'de> for AgeOrErrorField {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<AgeOrErrorField, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        struct AgeOrErrorFieldVisitor;

        impl<'de> serde::de::Visitor<'de> for AgeOrErrorFieldVisitor {
            type Value = AgeOrErrorField;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
                write!(formatter, "age or error")
            }

            fn visit_str<E>(self, value: &str) -> Result<AgeOrErrorField, E>
            where
                E: serde::de::Error,
            {
                Ok(match value {
                    "age" => AgeOrErrorField::Age,
                    "name" => AgeOrErrorField::Name,
                    "error" => AgeOrErrorField::Error,
                    _ => panic!("Unexpected field name: {}", value),
                })
            }
        }

        deserializer.deserialize_any(AgeOrErrorFieldVisitor)
    }
}

impl<'de> serde::Deserialize<'de> for AgeOrError {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<AgeOrError, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        deserializer.deserialize_map(AgeOrErrorVisitor)
    }
}

struct AgeOrErrorVisitor;

impl<'de> serde::de::Visitor<'de> for AgeOrErrorVisitor {
    type Value = AgeOrError;

    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(formatter, "age or error")
    }

    fn visit_map<A>(self, mut map: A) -> Result<AgeOrError, A::Error>
    where
        A: serde::de::MapAccess<'de>,
    {
        let mut age: Option<i32> = None;
        let mut name: Option<String> = None;
        let mut error: Option<String> = None;
        loop {
            match map.next_key()? {
                Some(AgeOrErrorField::Age) => age = map.next_value()?,
                Some(AgeOrErrorField::Name) => name = map.next_value()?,
                Some(AgeOrErrorField::Error) => error = map.next_value()?,
                None => break,
            }
        }
        if let Some(error) = error {
            Ok(AgeOrError::Error(MyError { error: error }))
        } else {
            Ok(AgeOrError::Age(MyAge {
                age: age.expect("!age"),
                name: name.expect("!name"),
            }))
        }
    }
}

fn get_results(ages: &[i32]) -> Vec<AgeOrError> {
    let mut results = Vec::with_capacity(ages.len());
    for &age in ages.iter() {
        if age < 100 && age > 0 {
            results.push(AgeOrError::Age(MyAge {
                age: age,
                name: String::from("The dude"),
            }));
        } else {
            results.push(AgeOrError::Error(MyError {
                error: format!("{} is invalid age", age),
            }));
        }
    }
    results
}

fn main() {
    let v = get_results(&[1, -6, 7]);
    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&v).expect("Can't serialize");
    println!("serialized: {}", serialized);
    let deserialized: Vec<AgeOrError> =
        serde_json::from_str(&serialized).expect("Can't deserialize");
    println!("deserialized: {:?}", deserialized);
}
```

Note that in deserialization we can't reuse the automatically generated deserializers because:

1. deserialization is kind of streaming the fields to us, we can't *peek* into the stringified JSON representation and guess what it is;
2. we don't have access to the `serde::de::Visitor` implementations that Serde generates.

Also I did a shortcut and `panic`ked on errors. In production code you'd want to return the proper Serde errors instead.

---

Another solution would be to make a merged structure with all fields optional, like this:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive; // 1.0.70
extern crate serde; // 1.0.70
extern crate serde_json; // 1.0.24

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MyError {
    error: String,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MyAge {
    age: i32,
    name: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct MyAgeOrError {
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    age: Option<i32>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    name: Option<String>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    error: Option<String>,
}

impl MyAgeOrError {
    fn from_age(age: MyAge) -> MyAgeOrError {
        MyAgeOrError {
            age: Some(age.age),
            name: Some(age.name),
            error: None,
        }
    }
    fn from_error(error: MyError) -> MyAgeOrError {
        MyAgeOrError {
            age: None,
            name: None,
            error: Some(error.error),
        }
    }
}

fn get_results(ages: &[i32]) -> Vec<MyAgeOrError> {
    let mut results = Vec::with_capacity(ages.len());
    for &age in ages.iter() {
        if age < 100 && age > 0 {
            results.push(MyAgeOrError::from_age(MyAge {
                age: age,
                name: String::from("The dude"),
            }));
        } else {
            results.push(MyAgeOrError::from_error(MyError {
                error: format!("{} is invalid age", age),
            }));
        }
    }
    results
}

fn main() {
    let v = get_results(&[1, -6, 7]);
    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&v).expect("Can't serialize");
    println!("serialized: {}", serialized);
    let deserialized: Vec<MyAgeOrError> =
        serde_json::from_str(&serialized).expect("Can't deserialize");
    println!("deserialized: {:?}", deserialized);
}
```

I'd vouch for this one because it allows the Rust structure (e.g. `MyAgeOrError`) to match the layout of your JSON. That way the JSON layout becomes documented in the Rust code.

P.S. Lately I tend to delay the decoding of optional or dynamically typed JSON parts with the help of [RawValue](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/struct.RawValue.html). It's tricky to serialize them though, because `RawValue` is a borrow. For instance, and to help with serialization, one can *intern* a `RawValue`, promoting it to the `'static` lifetime:

```
use serde_json::value::{RawValue as RawJson};

fn intern_raw_json(raw_json: Box<RawJson>) -> &'static RawJson {
    use parking_lot::Mutex;
    use std::mem::transmute;

    static BUF: Mutex<Vec<Pin<Box<RawJson>>>> = Mutex::new(Vec::new());

    let buf = BUF.lock();
    let raw_json: Pin<Box<RawJson>> = raw_json.into();
    let pt: &'static RawJson = {
        let pt: &RawJson = &*raw_json;
        transmute(pt)
    };
    buf.push(raw_json);
    pt
}
```

If performance is not an issue, then one can deserialize the dynamic parts into the [Value](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/enum.Value.html).
Similarly, if using `Value` is an option, then custom deserialization can be simplified by implementing [`TryFrom<Value>`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#try_from).

Comment: again simple things made difficult by rust

Comment: @nikoss, Serde was designed to be fast, and generic across multiple encoding formats. AFAIK, it's one of the fastest JSON libraries out there. (Last time I checked, only the memory-unsafe C++ rapidjson was faster). Some amount of static typing is a necessary trade-off, it allows us to decode directly into a structure, avoiding the heap allocation of temporaries. If you don't need the extra speed and the convenience of typed structures, you're welcome to keep things simple by using the dynamically-typed JSON libraries (or indeed the dynamically-typed part of Serde, via `serde_json::Value`).

Answer (score 14):

Serde supports [internally tagged](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#internally-tagged) and [untagged enums](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged) as of version 0.9.6.

The following code shows an example of how this could be done by using an enum with the attribute `#[serde(untagged)]`.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive; // 1.0.70
extern crate serde_json; // 1.0.24

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct MyError {
    error: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct MyAge {
    age: i32,
    name: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum AgeOrError {
    Age(MyAge),
    Error(MyError),
}

fn get_results(ages: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<AgeOrError> {
    let mut results = Vec::with_capacity(ages.len());
    for age in ages {
        if age < 100 && age > 0 {
            results.push(AgeOrError::Age(MyAge {
                age: age,
                name: String::from("The dude"),
            }));
        } else {
            results.push(AgeOrError::Error(MyError {
                error: format!("{} is invalid age", age),
            }));
        }
    }
    results
}

fn main() {
    let results = get_results(vec![1, -6, 7]);
    let json = serde_json::to_string(&results).unwrap();
    println!("{}", json);
}
```

The above code outputs the following JSON:

```
[{"age":1,"name":"The dude"},{"error":"-6 is invalid age"},{"age":7,"name":"The dude"}]
```

More information on Serde's enum representation can be found in the [overview](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html).