# Is there a way to convert any JSON type into String when deserializing?

Tags: json, rust, serde

I have the JSON

```json
["a", 1, 3, 4, 6]
```

I want to store it into

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Result {
    values: Vec<String>,
}
```

Is there some simple attribute which I'm missing to achieve this?

This is similar to [Convert two types into a single type with Serde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870428/convert-two-types-into-a-single-type-with-serde), but I'm hoping I wont have to implement anything custom.

Comment: You should derive `Deserialize` on the struct.

Comment: @Aplet123 that's not a valid solution to this question.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How can I use Serde with a JSON array with different objects for successes and errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37561593/155423); [How to transform fields during deserialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46753955/155423); [Convert two types into a single type with Serde](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37870428/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: TL;DR — no, someone has to write the custom logic.

Comment: I'm asking if there's something shorter than implementing my own deserializer

Comment: You can deserialize into [`Value`s](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html) or [`RawValue`s](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/struct.RawValue.html) instead of strings